# Generators contained in another subgroup generated by a subset.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I had come across the following exercise:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $S, T \subseteq G$ subsets of $G$.
>
> 1. Suppose $G$ is finite. Denote $S = \{s_1,\dots,s_k\}$. Suppose that for all $j \in \{1,\dots,k\}$ we have $s_j \in T$. Prove or
>    disprove: $\langle S \rangle$ is a subgroup of $\langle T \rangle$.
> 2. Now suppose $G$ is infinite. Without assuming whether $S$ or $T$ are finite or infinite, prove or disprove: If $S \subseteq T$, then $\langle S \rangle $ is a subgroup of $ \langle T \rangle$.
>
> Hint: $\langle S \rangle = \{s_1^{n_1} \dots s_m^{n_m} | m \in \mathbb N, s_1,\dots,s_m \in S, n_1,\dots,n_m \in \mathbb Z \}.$

I don't understand why there would be a difference between the finite and infinite case. Also, I'm having trouble using the definition given by the hint to show the first statement is true. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: The whole idea is to see that *there is no difference* between the finite and infinite case, and that the methods working in the finite setting works in the infinite as well. To show the two cases, you have to use the definition given in the hint directly. How do you show an inclusion in general? See what kinds of elements lie in one set, and show that any such element must also lie in the second set.

Answer (score 0):

Note a few things:

1. $\langle S\rangle$ is generated by the elements of $S$ (similar to the concept of a vector space basis generating the whole vector space)
2. since all the elements of $S$ are contained in $T$, $T$ is generated by the elements of $S$ and also (in case $S\neq T$) a few other Elements just contained in T.

Therefore all the elements that can be generated by $S$ can also be generated by $T$ and $\langle S\rangle \leq \langle T\rangle$

Answer (score 0):

The hint reflects the subtle definition of a *subgroup generated by a subset* $S$, whether or not this set is finite of infinite. The point is that infinite products in *abstract* groups do not exist / cannot be defined (the situation is different in for example topological groups).

Consider the following infinite product $\sigma$ in the infinite symmetric group $S_{\infty}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$: $\sigma=(12)(12)(12)\cdots$. So what is the value of $\sigma$? Is it $(1)$ or is it $(12)$? So even if your generating set is infinite in cardinality, the definition is $\langle S \rangle = \{s_1^{n_1} \dots s_m^{n_m} | m \in \mathbb N, s_1,\dots,s_m \in S, n_1,\dots,n_m \in \mathbb Z \}$, that is, you are considering only *finite* products of elements where the elements themselves can vary (infinitely) as long as they belong to $S$.

Another way to define a subgroup of group $G$ generated by a subset $S$: it is the unique smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $S$ (whenever $S \subseteq H \leq G$, then $\langle S \rangle \leq H$).

Answer (score 0):

You ask "I don't understand why there would be a difference between the finite and infinite case." As Tim* points out in the comments, there is no difference here. However, if we subtly change the definition of $\langle S\rangle$ then there *is* a difference.

To illustrate this, I suggest you complete the following two exercises. The only difference in the definitions of $\langle S \rangle$ and $\overline{\langle S \rangle}$ is that the $\mathbb{Z}$ is now an $\mathbb{N}$.

> Let $G$ be a group and let $S, T \subseteq G$ subsets of $G$. Define $\overline{\langle S \rangle} = \{s_1^{n_1} \dots s_m^{n_m} | m \in \mathbb N, s_1,\dots,s_m \in S, n_1,\dots,n_m \in \mathbb N \}.$
>
> 1. Suppose $G$ is finite. Prove or
>    disprove: $\langle S \rangle=\overline{\langle S \rangle}$.
> 2. Now suppose that $G$ contains an element of infinite order (so is infinite). Prove or disprove: $\langle S \rangle=\overline{\langle S \rangle}$.

*As some call them.